# UML for GWT RPC

Tags: java, gwt, uml, gwt-rpc

How do I draw a UML diagram for GWT RPC classes and interfaces.
These are the classes that I need to show on UML and their relationship.
Let's take an example from the [sample project in Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create). I has following classe/interfaces:

```
GreetingService.java, GreetingServiceAsync.java, GreetingServiceImpl.java
```

Where and how should GreetingServiceAsync.java should go on the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They already have a UML diagram drawn on this page:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC

GWT RPC is seen as "magic" to standard Java syntax, because they are creating a relationship between the GreetingService and GreetingServiceAsync interfaces when there isn't one (by standard Java syntax).  With GWT's compiler, when it sees an interface extending "RemoteService", they automatically expect that their is a paired interface by the same name + "Async", that implements the same method names (but they have a little different structure).

From Java syntax, the only thing that ties together the GreetingService and GreetingServiceAynx is the GWT.create call.  The relationship between the server-side GreetingServiceImpl and GreetingService is simple (the Impl implements the interface).

Comment: Thanks Kyrra, that's what I needed. Now I know that I need to draw a doted line and annotated is 'related'